# How to make adaptive Threshold at part on image in Opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv

Maybe my question is strange something but I need to make an adaptive Threshold on part of the image that the user selects with his mouse and that's my code

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("test.png")
# img2 = cv2.imread("flower.jpg")

# variables
ix = -1
iy = -1
drawing = False


def draw_reactangle_with_drag(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global ix, iy, drawing, img
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix = x
        iy = y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            img2 = cv2.imread("test.png")
            cv2.rectangle(img2, pt1=(ix, iy), pt2=(x, y),
                          color=(0, 255, 255), thickness=1)
            img = img2

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        img2 = cv2.imread("test.png")
        cv2.rectangle(img2, pt1=(ix, iy), pt2=(x, y),
                      color=(0, 255, 255), thickness=1)

        img = img2
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2[y: iy, x: ix], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,
                                   255,  # maximum value assigned to pixel values exceeding the threshold
                                   cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,  # gaussian weighted sum of neighborhood
                                   cv2.THRESH_BINARY,  # thresholding type
                                   5,  # block size (5x5 window)
                                   3)  # constant
        img = th


cv2.namedWindow(winname="Title of Popup Window")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Title of Popup Window", draw_reactangle_with_drag)

while True:
    cv2.imshow("Title of Popup Window", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and that's what I got at attached screen[image]
[image]
What am I missing?

Comment: Create a mask of the area you want (white on black background the size of your image). Do adaptive threshold on the whole image. Use the mask to merge between the two images. `np.where(mask==255, adaptive_threshold_image, input_image)`

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for your reply, sorry I'm a beginner can you edit my code, please?

Comment: I won't edit your code. But if you give me the coordinates of the region that you want, I will provide my code to threshold that area.

Comment: @fmw42 the coordinates are (364 396 359 453) as (y iy x ix)

Comment: What are iy and ix? Are those just the bottom right corner and y,x are the top left corner?

Comment: Cropping the image at the region around "No", then applying adaptive threshold should be fine. You may need to invert your threshold and then invert back after thresholding. Have you tried that? I am not sure without trying whether the adaptive threshold needs to work on white or black regions.

Comment: Also adjust your window size (5x5) seems too small and adjust your C constant as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution for the desired region in Python/OpenCV. It is to use division normalization rather than adaptive thresholding. (This may or may not work for other regions.)

- Read the input
- Specify crop coordinates for rectangle
- Crop the image
- Blur the cropped image
- Divide the input by the blurred image
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('equador.png')

# specify the crop rectangle
# 364 396 359 453   (y iy x ix)
x1 = 359
y1 = 364
x2 = 453
y2 = 396

# crop the input
crop = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]

# blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(crop, (0,0), sigmaX=99, sigmaY=99)

# divide
divide = cv2.divide(crop, blur, scale=255)

# put the divide back into the input
result = img.copy()
result[y1:y2, x1:x2] = divide

# save results
cv2.imwrite('equador_crop.png', crop)
cv2.imwrite('equador_crop_blur.png', blur)
cv2.imwrite('equador_crop_divide.png', divide)
cv2.imwrite('equador_crop_divide_result.png', result)


# show results
cv2.imshow('crop', crop)
cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('divide', divide)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Cropped Image:

[image]

Blurred Image:

[image]

Division Normalized Crop:

[image]

Division Normalized Replace:

[image]

Note: you may prefer to convert the cropped image to grayscale before blurring and then divide the grayscale version by the blurred image.

Comment: it's amazing but still, need a last thing please how to add the Division Normalized Result into the original image, or how to replace that square from the original image with that image?

Comment: Somehow my code got deleted. I have added it back and edited it to show how to put the crop back into the image after processing. But please read up on Numpy slicing. It is a core functionality that you will need to master.

Comment: Thank you sir very very much you saved me ^_^ , yup I will read about it :) :)